# Can I make my for loop in a for loop more efficient?

Tags: r

The purpose of my R-script is to extract a column of data points from a data frame, then make linear regression on a stretch of 10 data points, save the coefficients and then continue with the next 10 data points until all data points of the column has been used (EDIT: To be more clear, here I mean making regression on data point 1-10, then 2-11, then 3-12, then 4-13 etc). All coefficients from the same column are then sorted and the the average of the 5 highest values are stored in a new data frame. The script then continues to the next column of the original data frame and does the entire regression again, storing the mean of the top coefficient in the "coefficient" data frame.
The code can be seen below:

```
    file_list <- list.files(path=getwd())

    df <- read_excel(file_list[1])
    name_vector <- colnames(df)
    regressors<-setdiff(names(df),"Time [min]")

n = 33  
coef2 <- data.frame()
coef3 <- data.frame()

#dat <- data.frame(df[[1]],df[[n]])

for (i in 1:length(regressors)) {
  dat <- data.frame(df[[1]], df[[(i + 1)]])
  for (i in 1:length(dat[[1]])) {
    temp_data <- dat[i:(i + 15),]
    linm <- lm(temp_data[[2]] ~ temp_data[[1]], data = temp_data)
    Inter <- summary(linm)$coefficients[1]
    Slope <- summary(linm)$coefficients[2]
    coef2 <-
      rbindlist(list(coef2, data.frame(Inter, Slope)), use.names = T)
  }
  mean <- coef2 %>%
    arrange(desc(Slope)) %>%
    slice(2:7)
  meanx <-  sapply(mean, FUN = mean)
  meanx <-
    data.frame(lapply(meanx, type.convert), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  coef3 <-  rbindlist(list(coef3, meanx), use.names = T)
  coef2 <- data.frame()
  z <- function(x)
    (meanx[[2]] * x + meanx[[1]])
  p <- qplot(dat[[1]],dat[[2]], data=dat, xlab="X-axis", ylab="Y-axis")+ylim(0,(max(dat[[2]], na.rm = TRUE)+100))
  b <- stat_function(fun=z)
  v <- print(p + b)
}
```

With some example data here:

```
Time    A   B   C
330 102 179 303
340 103 194 308
350 101 198 348
360 114 199 347
370 120 214 371
380 131 224 420
390 128 226 430
400 128 246 481
410 138 260 541
420 146 277 583
430 155 290 640
440 154 315 653
```

The code works as I want it to, but is really slow to execute. Can I somehow make it more efficient. I'm fairly new to R, so much of this code is stitched together from various sources.

Thanks in advance
-William

Comment: For future reference, this kind of question about how to improve working code might be a better fit for the [Code Review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [**slider** package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=slider)
specializes in helping with these kinds of rolling operations. When used
with a data frame, the `slide()` functions apply a function for each window
of rows in the data. You could use that to power the model fitting process.

First read the example data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
Time   A   B   C
 330 102 179 303
 340 103 194 308
 350 101 198 348
 360 114 199 347
 370 120 214 371
 380 131 224 420
 390 128 226 430
 400 128 246 481
 410 138 260 541
 420 146 277 583
 430 155 290 640
 440 154 315 653")
```

We can then replace the outer loop over outcomes with `map_dfr()` which
combines the results in a data frame, and the inner loop with `slide_dfr()`
which does the same, but for a window of rows:

```r
window_width <- 10
outcomes <- c("A", "B", "C")

# Estimate coefficients for each outcome
coefs <- map_dfr(set_names(outcomes), function(outcome) {
  # Fit model for each complete window in `df`
  slider::slide_dfr(df, function(data) {
    # Build model formula for outcome and fit
    f <- reformulate("Time", outcome)
    m <- lm(formula = f, data = data)
    set_names(coef(m), c("Inter", "Slope"))
  }, .after = window_width - 1, .complete = TRUE, .names_to = "Window")
}, .id = "Outcome")

coefs
#>   Outcome Window       Inter     Slope
#> 1       A      1   -67.30909 0.5024242
#> 2       A      2   -89.20000 0.5600000
#> 3       A      3   -87.54545 0.5545455
#> 4       B      1  -158.98182 1.0151515
#> 5       B      2  -191.86667 1.1030303
#> 6       B      3  -265.72727 1.2927273
#> 7       C      1  -749.07273 3.0993939
#> 8       C      2  -939.80000 3.6018182
#> 9       C      3 -1019.60000 3.8000000
```

Note that we kept the coefficients from all windows above, not just the top
5. It’s best to save the summarization of results to be done outside the
loops, if you have enough memory for it. That way, if you decide that you
wanted a different summary after all, you won’t have to redo the expensive
part of fitting the models.

With the coefficients in a neat data frame, it’s straightforward to
summarize:

```r
n_top_slopes <- 5

mean_top_coefs <- coefs %>% 
  group_by(Outcome) %>% 
  slice_max(Slope, n = n_top_slopes) %>%
  summarise(across(c(Inter, Slope), mean))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)

mean_top_coefs
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   Outcome  Inter Slope
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A        -81.4 0.539
#> 2 B       -206.  1.14 
#> 3 C       -903.  3.50
```

A quick way to plot these linear fits with the data would be with `geom_abline()`:

```r
df_long <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = all_of(outcomes),
    names_to = "Outcome",
    values_to = "Value"
  )

scatterplot <- function() {
  ggplot(df_long, aes(Time, Value)) +
    facet_wrap(~ Outcome) + geom_point()
}

scatterplot() +
  geom_abline(data = mean_top_coefs, aes(intercept = Inter, slope = Slope))
```

[image]

A slightly more involved but more general approach would be to consturct
a new data frame of predictions first, and plot with `geom_line()`:

```r
mean_top_fits <- df_long %>% 
  inner_join(mean_top_coefs, by = "Outcome") %>% 
  mutate(Value = Inter + Slope * Time)

scatterplot() + geom_line(data = mean_top_fits)
```

[image]

Using this method, we could e.g. plot the fits for each individual window:

```r
time_range <- function(window) {
  range(df$Time[seq(window, window + window_width - 1)])
}

# Calculate predicted lines for each window
window_fits <- coefs %>% 
  mutate(Time = map(Window, time_range)) %>% 
  unnest_longer(Time) %>% 
  mutate(Value = Inter + Slope * Time)

scatterplot() + geom_line(data = window_fits, aes(group = Window))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is really a cool way to do it. Maybe you could help me with one last thing. In my own code, I plot a line corresponding to the mean slope and intersection on top of the data, in order to see how it fits. How would you do that in your code?

Comment: Yup sure! A couple of ways come to mind; I edited accordingly. There's some shortcuts because we're just plotting a straight line. If you had a more complex model, I'd probably save the fitted model objects instead of just the coefficients, and then use `predict()` to get the fits to avoid manually crafting the predictions from the coefficients.

Comment: That is just so great! Thanks a bunch my dude. I just started using R last week and with no other programming experience, it took most of 2 days to write my version of the script. It's really useful to see the code written in a more efficient way although I'm still not entirely sure what some of the individual lines does.

Comment: Happy to help! That's impressive progress for having just started out! This solution definitely involves quite a few concepts that may take some time to wrap your head around.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure the code you posted works exactly as you want: you are using the same index for your nested `for` loops (`i` in both cases), so I'd expect the internal loop may rewrite the external one [edit: actually not: see comments]. Also, when I try to execute this code, the definition of `dat` fails: when `i` is equal to the number of columns, then `i+1` is outside of the data frame. And finally the code doesn't correspond exactly to your description, e.g. taking 10 elements or 15, etc.

I tried to write a pure dplyr version based on your description, I'm not sure I understood everything though. It should be faster than the version with the for loop, but it's hard to be sure since we're currently not doing the same thing.

Let's first process a single column. To slice the column into groups of 10 observations, I define a function:

```
library(tidyverse)

make_groups <- function(n, k){
  # return a factor of length n defining groups of size k, except the last one
  nb_groups <- floor(n/k)
  overhang <- n - k*nb_groups
  c(rep(1:nb_groups, each = k), rep(nb_groups+1, overhang))
}
```

And some parameters

```
# how many rows to group together
group_size <- 10
# how many top coefs to use for mean
mean_top <- 2
```

Now, I'll have several steps: first, add a column to group the rows 10 by 10. Then run the `lm()`. Since the result of `lm()` is a complex object, I store it as a list-column. Then, I can simply do a `mutate()` to extract the coefficients of interest, and a `summarize()` to group the observations and only keep the mean of the top ones.

```
df %>%
  mutate(group = make_groups(n(), k=group_size)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(mod = list(lm(A~Time))) %>%
  mutate(intercept = map_dbl(mod, ~.x$coefficients[[1]]),
         slope = map_dbl(mod, ~ .x$coefficients[[2]])) %>%
  summarize(mean_intercept = mean(sort(intercept, decreasing = TRUE)[1:mean_top]),
            mean_slope = mean(sort(slope,decreasing = TRUE)[1:mean_top]))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#   mean_intercept mean_slope
#            <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1           65.3      0.201
```

This seems to work, so now how do we run it for every column? One possibility would be to use `across()`, but it gets complicated and unreadable, so I'll go with a simpler loop approach. Rather than a `for` loop, I use the equivalent `map_df()`, which does the looping and formatting by itself:

```
map_df(colnames(df)[2:4],
       function(cur_col_name){
         df %>%
           mutate(group = make_groups(n(), k=group_size)) %>%
           group_by(group) %>%
           summarize(mod = list(lm(formula(paste0(cur_col_name,"~Time")))),
                     .groups = "drop") %>%
           mutate(intercept = map_dbl(mod, ~.x$coefficients[[1]]),
                  slope = map_dbl(mod, ~ .x$coefficients[[2]])) %>%
           summarize(mean_intercept = mean(sort(intercept, decreasing = TRUE)[1:mean_top]),
                     mean_slope = mean(sort(slope,decreasing = TRUE)[1:mean_top]),
                     .groups = "drop")
       }
)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   mean_intercept mean_slope
#            <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1           65.3      0.201
# 2         -472.       1.76 
# 3         -334.       2.20
```

So, finally we can compare performance (but since the two functions are not doing the same thing, that's not very meaningful). After resetting everything (ctrl+shift+F10 on RStudio) I run this:

```
library(tidyverse)
ex_df <- read.table(text="Time    A   B   C
330 102 179 303
340 103 194 308
350 101 198 348
360 114 199 347
370 120 214 371
380 131 224 420
390 128 226 430
400 128 246 481
410 138 260 541
420 146 277 583
430 155 290 640
440 154 315 653",header=TRUE)




with_for_loop <- function(df){
  regressors<-setdiff(names(df),"Time")
  
  coef2 <- data.frame()
  coef3 <- data.frame()
  
  #dat <- data.frame(df[[1]],df[[n]])
  
  for (i in 1:length(regressors)) {
    dat <- data.frame(df[[1]], df[[(i + 1)]])
    for (i in 1:length(dat[[1]])) {
      temp_data <- dat[i:(i + 15),]
      linm <- lm(temp_data[[2]] ~ temp_data[[1]], data = temp_data)
      Inter <- summary(linm)$coefficients[1]
      Slope <- summary(linm)$coefficients[2]
      coef2 <-
        data.table::rbindlist(list(coef2, data.frame(Inter, Slope)), use.names = T)
    }
    mean <- coef2 %>%
      arrange(desc(Slope)) %>%
      slice(2:7)
    meanx <-  sapply(mean, FUN = mean)
    meanx <-
      data.frame(lapply(meanx, type.convert), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    coef3 <-  data.table::rbindlist(list(coef3, meanx), use.names = T)
    coef2 <- data.frame()
    # z <- function(x)
    #   (meanx[[2]] * x + meanx[[1]])
    # p <- qplot(dat[[1]],dat[[2]], data=dat, xlab="X-axis", ylab="Y-axis")+ylim(0,(max(dat[[2]], na.rm = TRUE)+100))
    # b <- stat_function(fun=z)
    # v <- print(p + b)
  }
  coef3
}


make_groups <- function(n, k){
  # return a factor of length n defining groups of size k, except the last one
  nb_groups <- floor(n/k)
  overhang <- n - k*nb_groups
  c(rep(1:nb_groups, each = k), rep(nb_groups+1, overhang))
}

# how many rows to group together
group_size <- 10
# how many top coefs to use for mean
mean_top <- 2

with_map <- function(df){
  map_df(colnames(df)[2:4],
         function(cur_col_name){
           df %>%
             mutate(group = make_groups(n(), k=group_size)) %>%
             group_by(group) %>%
             summarize(mod = list(lm(formula(paste0(cur_col_name,"~Time")))),
                       .groups = "drop") %>%
             mutate(intercept = map_dbl(mod, ~.x$coefficients[[1]]),
                    slope = map_dbl(mod, ~ .x$coefficients[[2]])) %>%
             summarize(mean_intercept = mean(sort(intercept, decreasing = TRUE)[1:mean_top]),
                       mean_slope = mean(sort(slope,decreasing = TRUE)[1:mean_top]),
                       .groups = "drop")
         }
  )
}
```

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(with_for_loop(ex_df),
                               with_map(ex_df))
# Unit: milliseconds
#                  expr     min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
#  with_for_loop(ex_df) 65.2575 73.36925 81.36406 77.4504 83.82025 223.8993   100
#       with_map(ex_df) 39.2748 42.54920 47.53608 45.7630 49.27740  92.4213   100
```

So the `dplyr` approach is 2x as fast, that's not very impressive. But I expect it might get better on a bigger dataset (because you have assignments in your `for` loop that I suspect might choke on big datasets).

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Yes, I may not have been very clear in my initial description. What I meant by "every 10 data points" was really that I wanted to make regression on data points 1-10, then 2-11, then 3-12, then 4-13 and so on. But I think I should be able to take your code and modify it to do just that.

Comment: The double `i` loop is actually _kind of_ fine. The inner loop only rewrites `i` for the remainder of the outer loop's body, but doesn't mess up the counter itself, like it would in some other languages. I actually only just recently read about this in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/) section 8.1.64 and found it quite surprising!

Comment: Surprising indeed! I added a note, I still think it's a bad idea to rely on that (seems like a great way to get unexpected results when trying to use the wrong `i`).

Comment: Yeah definitely. I'd wager it was likely a happy accident here that the outer loop's `i` wasn't referred to after running the inner loop -- that wouldn't have worked out well.